# How do I write the table structure in Oracle from an existing schema?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-scripts, data-dictionary

I have so far figured out that to describe a table I can use the below:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','<my table name>','<table owner>') from dual;
```

I also found that I can get a list of tables from the **current user** using the below statement:

```
select table_name from user_tables;
```

However I need to find a way to combine these two so I get a (preferably SQL file) output which basically describes all the tables in the current schema. How can I go about that?

Comment: if you want to do it programmatically - just run the first query in a loopu. otherwise, get any Oracle IDE (Oracle SQL developer, for instance) - they all have some sort of schema export utilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `dbms_metadata` in your query on `user_tables`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE',table_name,user) 
from   user_tables;
```